# Installing Packages Takes A Very Long Time on Ubuntu

Tags: r, installation

I was using Windows as OS and RStudio for windows, switched to Ubuntu today and installed R and RStudio again. When I try to install some packages from CRAN (only `tidyverse` !) using `install.packages()`, I see something something on console I have never seen on Windows, it looks like this;

```
* installing *source* package ‘data.table’ ...
** package ‘data.table’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
gcc -std=gnu99 9.3.0
zlib 1.2.11 is available ok
OpenMP supported
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-5iUtQS/r-base-4.0.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c assign.c -o assign.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-5iUtQS/r-base-4.0.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c between.c -o between.o
```

...

then it continues like this and installing process is taking much longer than the time I encountered on Windows. (`tidyverse` which includes about seven packages took 30 minutes)

Is this normal ? if it is not, how can I solve it ?

Comment: by default, R on windows installs binary packages (no compilation required), R on linux installs source packages (compilation required).

Comment: thanks for information, is not there a way to reduce the installing time ?

Comment: @r2evans explains why you get those messages; I would suggest taking a look at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html for some info on how to install such packages *without* the need for compilation. With some minimal setup, you can install them as binary packages (no compilation required) using Ubuntu's package manager rather than installing from R (e.g. you can do `sudo apt install r-cran-tidyverse` to install `tidyverse` much more quickly than `install.packages("tidyverse")`

Comment: thank you ! this suggestion sound helpful, is it available for every package that situated in CRAN repository ?

Comment: I don't think so, but for most of the most popular ones

Comment: according to that web page there are "4000+" binary packages on the PPA. That's about a quarter of the packages on CRAN at the moment (although don't know if that number has been updated recently)

Comment: @BenBolker I've just tried this method but couldn't do it again. When I try to install a package by using sudo apt , says "The following packages have unmet dependencies" and give me a list contains lots of unmet package

Comment: don't know offhand, sorry.  FWIW the package-installing pain is  mostly front-loaded; once you have most of the packages you want installed, you only have to deal with installation/updating occasionally.

Comment: Hasn't RStudio started fronting a binary-package mirror of CRAN somewhere for just this issue?

Comment: Yes ... see https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/07/01/announcing-public-package-manager/. It is effectively a CRAN mirror but for **linux binary packages** (which are not normally available on CRAN mirrors).

Comment: @r2evans I can't explain how thankful I am, totally uprooted my issue. Now installing packages takes time as Windows takes !!!!!

Answer (score 13):

A summary of the comments that helped resolve the issue.

---

In general, the default installation method in linux is `type="source"`, which means that any package with non-R source code (e.g., C++, Fortran) needs to be compiled. Further, CRAN and all of its repository mirrors only provide binary packages windows and macos.

It appears that there are two ways to install binary packages on linux vice the default:

1. @duckmayr's suggestion to read https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html (similar pages exist for other linux distros) identifies how to set up the CRAN2deb4ubuntu PPA, so that one can the the OS-level software management `apt` (and related tools). These ubuntu/debian packages are maintained well and reasonably up-to-date, though not nearly as frequently updated as a straight-shot to the CRAN servers.

   But instead of the long-running R command `install.packages("tidyverse")`, you can simply run this for a binary installation, same effect:

   ```bash
   $ sudo apt-get install r-cran-tidyverse
   ```

   Unfortunately, the PPA does not include every single contributed package supplied to CRAN (as that would take significant effort on the PPA maintainers' side, trying to keep up with CRAN's daily onslaught of new packages and package-updates ... the testing alone sounds prohibitive). (The number suggested is 4000+ packages in the PPA, out of CRAN's 16,278 packages (as of 30 seconds ago).
2. A recent addition to the repository scene is RStudio's [Public Package Manager](https://packagemanager.rstudio.com). In a recent blog post, RStudio announced it to have (at least) three fundamental features:

   - *Access to pre-compiled packages on Linux via `install.packages` ...*
   - *Historical checkpoints for CRAN enabling reproducible work ...*
   - *Expanded Windows support for older versions of R ...*

   (That's just a small snapshot of the blog post, I suggest you read the original for more details and context.)

   A quick search (of packages for Ubuntu 20.04 Focal) reveals: 15,217 binary and 16,216 source packages.

   Borrowing from RStudio's ["Setup"](https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/client/#/repos/1/overview) page, for Ubuntu 20.04 Focal you can set this as your repository with

   ```r
   options(repos = c(PkgMgr="https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest"))
   ```

   (I named it "PkgMgr", that's arbitrary. You may want/need more repos, over to you, see [`?options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html) and [`?setRepository`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/setRepositories.html). This is a sample only, provided for convenience; please go to RStudio's documentation for how to set up your R for your installation.)